# Symfony 3.2.4 wildcard routing causes 100% cpu utilization

Tags: php, apache, symfony, cpu-usage

I have very strange problem:

I have two routes:
First one comes with wildcard:

```
/**
 * @Route("/test/{test}", name="test")
 * @param type $route
 */
public function testAction(Request $request, $test) {

    return $this->render('resource/showResource.html.twig', [
                'test' => $test
    ]);
}
```

Second one is without wildcard:

```
/**
 * @Route("/test", name="test")
 * @param type $route
 */
public function testAction(Request $request) {

    return $this->render('resource/showResource.html.twig', [
                'test' => 'something'
    ]);
}
```

**The problem is when I'm running first one (http://localhost/app_dev.php/test/1) my CPU utilization reaches almost 100% (process: httpd.exe => Apache HTTP Server.**

There is no such a problem with second one.

What thing could be causing this?

Comment: Is there any specific requirement for the {$test}? Means it should be only integer or something etc...?

Comment: Eventually it has to be integer, but right now it's not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved: 
in file base.html.twig I had not working lines like this:

```
    <script src="../vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Right now I am using assets for them and everything works like a charm.

Thanks for everyones effort! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * @Route("/test/{test}", name="test")
 */
public function testAction($test) {

    return $this->render('resource/showResource.html.twig', [
       'test' => $test
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Removing Request $request did not helped.

Comment: I removed the param option. That wasn't right. This function looks oke now, so the problem is somewhere else. Look at the form.

Comment: No effect. And I'm not using forms for now, it's just a test method.

Comment: Ou... it seems that showResource.html.twig or base.html.twig causing this problem. When I remove from showResource.html.twig this line:
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}
then everything works like a charm. But I need this line.

Answer (score 0):

Try as below may be it will help you:

```
/**
 * @Route("/test/{test}", name="test", requirements={"test": "\d+"})
 * @param type $route
 */
public function testAction(Request $request, $test) {

    return $this->render('resource/showResource.html.twig', [
            'test' => $test
    ]);
}
```

Check more details on http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#adding-wildcard-requirements

Comment: Unfortunately the CPU usage is still the same and I was trying to use requirements, without any effect. In my previous projects I had no such problems, everything was working.